# Graph API Failure Error while requesting token : The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood

Tags: azure, api, graph, registration, cisco

I am working to connect our Cisco email appliance to azure active directory. This requires a private key and cert to be generated via XCA and then imported into Azure and the appliance. I have registered the app per their guide in azure, granted it rights to Graph API and also granted it admin consent. When i run a test connection from the cisco appliance i get the following error:

Error while requesting token : The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.

To test if my permissions / consent worked i connected to the app from powershell using the client secret and pulled the token and ran that against graph explorer and it returned proper results.

Has any one has luck connecting a azure app using a certificate and private key?

Comment: You'll want to make sure the resource URI / scope is for the correct API. What have you configured for that?

Comment: I have not configured that. Would that be under "Expose an API" and then Scopes defined by this API?

Comment: Ahh, actually, no. What I'm curious is how the appliance is configured.

Comment: I have access to the appliance, but there is really no settings i can change around the connector